# Can't pybindgen to work with gccxml

Tags: python, c++, pybindgen

I have a C++ library I would like to bind to Python. I began using Pybindgen, and it is really easy to use, but manually adding functions and namespaces will take a long time considering the size of my C++ library. I've read through the documentation on PyBindGen, specifically, the gccxml portion that supposedly scans header files for me. This would be ideal, yet I can't get it to function properly. Just as a test, I inputted my main header file and tried to export it, but I get this error:

```
python bindinggenerator.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bindinggenerator.py", line 16, in <module>
    main()
  File "bindinggenerator.py", line 9, in main
    module = module_parser.parse("include\\PhospheneEngine.h")
  File "C:\Users\paolo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pybindgen\gccxmlparser.py", line 598, in parse
    pygen_classifier, gccxml_options)
  File "C:\Users\paolo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pybindgen\gccxmlparser.py", line 658, in parse_init
    assert isinstance(header_files, list)
AssertionError
```

And of course my Python code is basically just the modified example from [here](http://pythonhosted.org/PyBindGen/tutorial.html#header-file-scanning-with-py-gccxml).

```
import sys

import pybindgen
from pybindgen import FileCodeSink
from pybindgen.gccxmlparser import ModuleParser

def main():
    module_parser = ModuleParser('PhospheneEngine', '::')
    module = module_parser.parse("include\\PhospheneEngine.h")
    module.add_include("'include\\PhospheneEngine.h'")

    pybindgen.write_preamble(FileCodeSink(sys.stdout))
    module.generate(FileCodeSink(sys.stdout))

if (__name__ == '__main__'):
    main()
```

I have both gccxml installed and pygccxml (For Python 3.5) installed. The documentation really doesn't say too much about this process, so possibly a quick rundown of how to use this feature would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The parse function takes a list of headers.

```
module = module_parser.parse(["include\\PhospheneEngine.h"])
```